# Launching PHP code without visiting the website

Tags: php

I am running a PHP code on my website, and I need it to run everyday on set hour, but sometimes I can't visit the website to launch the code. Is there a way to set it so it launches itself?

Comment: Use a task scheduler, like cron on Linux, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853057/best-way-to-periodically-execute-a-php-script

Comment: @MateuszBartkowski please consider accepting one of the answers to appreciate the effort of those who wrote them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a CRON and add your task PHP.

A CRON, it's a manager for your tasks. You can configure when you want execute a command.

The CRON manager is natively available with the command **crontab**. You will find the documentation with **man crontab** and you can edit the tasks recorded with **crontab -e**. Caution to use the good user.

If you use Windows, I am not a Windows user but there are few eecutable to manage it. You can find more information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638124/cron-like-system-for-windows).

Comment: Don't forget, to take the code away from `public_html` if you don't want users to be able to execute it. You can still execute scripts out of `public_html` using `cron`

Answer (score 2):

IF your Provider does not support cron jobs, you can use online cron job services. Here are a few simple ones:

- [setcronjob](https://www.setcronjob.com/)
- [webcron](https://webcron.org/en)
- [easycron](http://www.easycron.com/)
- [cronjobservices](http://www.cronjobservices.com/)

But since it is 2014 you might want to consider more modern concepts like using a PaaS hoster that has Worker Services. Read up on that [here](http://www.iron.io/worker).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cron.
However, from terminal (I'm sure in Unix-like OSs, in Windows I don't know) you can use the command

```
php myFile.php
```

to call the file.