# Scheduling console apps

Tags: windows, console, scheduler

Does anyone have better ways of managing / scheduling console apps, without the use of Windows Scheduler?

eg. Console app to pickup records in the database that requires a set of actions.

*** Experience in the past, when number of tasks increase over time, it get's bit messy and difficult to maintain when moving servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are third party apps you could look at, some of which are suggested in [Cron-like system for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638124/cron-like-system-for-windows).

However, if Windows Scheduler does provide the functionality you need, but just not the ideal management, you could look at using the CLI [`schtasks.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can define all your tasks in an [XML schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383609(v=vs.85).aspx) meaning they will more easily port across machines.